# Programatically reading / writing Google Hangouts SMS

Tags: google-hangouts, hangouts-api

How can I read and respond to SMS messages to my Google Hangouts number programmatically? I have read a lot of conflicting information about whether or not it's currently possible to use Jabber / XMPP with Google Hangouts, and the so-called "Hangouts API" seems to really only work for creating a Google App and not meant for the use of one person. I want this to work with my current Google account, so creating a new Google App is not really an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tdryer's [hangups](https://github.com/tdryer/hangups) was the most helpful library I found for doing this.